# Piping the output of a program that doesn't write to stdout

Tags: bash

I'm looking for the best way to use pipes when the input program doesn't write to stdout. Specifically I want to pipe `objcopy` into `hexdump` like this

```
objcopy -I ifmt -O binary ifile - | hexdump -C
```

but objcopy doesn't accept '-' as a file meaning 'write to stdout' as some programs do.

At the moment I am doing

```
objcopy -I ifmt -O binary ifile tmpfile; hexdump -C tmpfile; rm tmpfile
```

but was wondering if there was a better way.

I am using bash 4.1.10 on cygwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a comment prescribing a process substitution, but it can't work for `objcopy` since `objcopy` will try to open a seekable file (as it may need to move back and forth in the file).

In short: `objcopy` can't write to a stream as `stdout`, that's why its output must be a *file* that can be seeked. Your solution is very likely the only reasonable possibility.

---

To answer your question

> I'm looking for the best way to use pipes when the input program doesn't write to stdout

in a more general fashion (but that's not applicable with `objcopy` or any command that requires seeking the file), in Bash you can use process substitution: if `mycommand` takes a parameter that is an output file, and doesn't accept `-` for standard output and doesn't write to standard output by default, you can use it as:

```
mycommand >(cat)
```

or if you want to pipe it through, e.g., `hexdump -C`:

```
mycommand >(hexdump -C)
```

With this, `mycommand` will see an argument of the form `/dev/fd/42` (where 42 may differ), and will be able to open it for writing, as if it where a regular file (but not seekable), and `hexdump` will get on its standard input the written data.

You can experiment process substitution like so: call the following script `mycommand`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 ]]; then
    echo "Hi, this is mycommand, and I was called with first argument: \`$1'"
    echo "I'm outputting this to the file given as argument" > "$1"
else
    echo >&2 "Please provide an argument (file to write to)"
    exit 1
fi
```

This script makes sure that you give a non-empty argument (otherwise shows an error message), outputs this argument to standard output, and a little line in the file the name of which is given as argument.

Then `chmod +x mycommand` and play with it:

```
$ ./mycommand
Please provide an argument (file to write to)
$ ./mycommand -
Hi, this is mycommand, and I was called with first argument: `-'
$ ls
- mycommand
$ rm ./-
$ ./mycommand >(cat)
Hi, this is mycommand, and I was called with first argument: `/dev/fd/63'
I'm outputting this to the file given as argument
$ ./mycommand >(tr -d e)
Hi, this is mycommand, and I was called with first argument: `/dev/fd/63'
I'm outputting this to th fil givn as argumnt
$ ./mycommand >(hexdump -C)
Hi, this is mycommand, and I was called with first argument: `/dev/fd/63'
00000000  49 27 6d 20 6f 75 74 70  75 74 74 69 6e 67 20 74  |I'm outputting t|
00000010  68 69 73 20 74 6f 20 74  68 65 20 66 69 6c 65 20  |his to the file |
00000020  67 69 76 65 6e 20 61 73  20 61 72 67 75 6d 65 6e  |given as argumen|
00000030  74 0a                                             |t.|
00000032
$ ./mycommand >(cat) > /dev/null
I'm outputting this to the file given as argument
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way if you use `zsh`

`(){objcopy -O binary -j .text <input file> $1; cat $1} =(touch -c .) | hexdump -C`

**Explanation**

- `=()` is zsh process substitution, which supports the seeking property needed.
- `$1` inside the function body referes to the file created by `=(touch -c .)`.

  - Note that the cmd "`touch -c .`"
  - `-c` is `---no-create` so the command itself does nothing, we are simply using it for the side effect `=()` has, which is a temporary file `zsh` creates containing the output of `touch -c .` (which is nothing) and deletes once the command is finished.
- `(){}` is anonymous function syntax which keeps the file created by `=()` inside the function body around long enough to be `cat`'ed to `stdout`.

Comment: Bonus, I checked again and apparently you don't even need to use the ```touch -c .``` but can leave it empty. So it looks like ```(){objcopy -O binary -j .text <input file> $1; cat $1} =() | hexdump -C```